# Where is the code for a customized list NewForm.aspx page in sp2007

Tags: list-form, custom-list

I have to maintain a sharepoint solution that I did not build myself. For a custom list "Files", that is provisioned as a feature in this solution, a newform.aspx shows a non default page. for example a button for spellign checker is added and not all of the listfields ar shown. Because I have not enough "reputations" for this site I'm not allowed to show a picture in this post. But in this Url you can see a screenprint:
http://sharepointleren.files.wordpress.com/2012/02/newform.jpg

the url is like:
http://app.dev.local/apps/example/Lists/Files/NewForm.aspx

I can not find where I can adjust this page. The page itself is not part of the solution and I do not know how to hook into the code using the debugger in Visual Sudio. Still this modification, for example see the "spelling checker" is provisioned in this solution and not with sharepoint desigener or another tool. I have the same riddle for EditForm.aspx
In the list schema.xml these pages are defined in a standard way:

```
<Forms>
  <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
  <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
  <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
</Forms>
```

Does anyone have a clue? Where can I find the code for changing for example the order in which the fields are displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the schema xml for the custom list you can define which fields will be displayed on which form with the following entries for a field in the list:
ShowInEditForm="FALSE"
ShowInNewForm="FALSE"

The order in which the fields are shown is the order in the contenttype.
And finally the button for the spelling checker was added in with javascript on the masterpage.
So it is not one place where to look for, if you wonder how the newform.aspx is composed.